# How to make a fixed div stay in the same place regardless of zooming while scrolling a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y > 350) {
        $(".csw-step4-price-summary").css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '40%',
            'left': '0%'
    });

    } else {
        $(".csw-step4-price-summary").css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '40%',
            'left': '0px'
        });
    }

});
```

HTML :

```
 <div class="csw-step4-third" style="position: relative; float: right; width: 33%; height: 600px">
        <div class="csw-step4-price-summary">
           @Html.Partial(PartialViewsCo‌​nstants.PriceSummary‌​)
        </div>
  </div>
```

I am sure you already grasped I want it with a position absolute till I reach 350px and then I want it changed to fixed and stay fixed when i am scrolling. Everything was fine until I changed resolution of the browser window. Fixed div moves to left or right depending on if i zoom in or out. Any ideas how to solve it? I have already tried to make a parent div with position relative, but I have read that position fixed takes the div out of the flow of the document, making the div with position relative redundant.

Thanks!

Comment: resolution of the screen or resolution of the browser window?

Comment: of the browser window, my bad.

Comment: That sounds weird, do you have a reference where we could see it? A codepen maybe? Check this out: https://codepen.io/blmstr/pen/XgVMqQ, so there it's always sticky to the left even if you zoom

Comment: My guess is that the fixed element is contained inside another. So it sticks to the left of its container, but if the container doesn't stick to the left edge of the window, then the fixed element won't either. @Kika what's your HTML markup?

Comment: @Jeremy. It is indeed contained, but the results were all the same even when it wasn't. Here it is:  <div class="csw-step4-third" style="position: relative; float: right; width: 33%; height: 600px">
                    <div class="csw-step4-price-summary">@Html.Partial(PartialViewsConstants.PriceSummary)</div>
                </div>

Comment: I doubt it behaved the same way free and contained. From your markup, it's contained inside a div that's `width:33%` and `float:right`, so it makes perfect sense that the fixed element inside can't stick to the window. Get it out of here and place it in the `body`.

Comment: Believe me, I tried to take it out of any parent and place it in the body and when i zoom in it still goes right and if i zoom out it goes the other way.